# Find filled regions given its boundaries in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, image-segmentation

I have a binary image with boundaries, like this one:

[image]

I want to find a binary image that contains the filled regions corresponding to those boundaries. I did it manually on Paint, and the result should look like this:

[image]

I've been looking for a solution, and I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310489/filling-holes-in-objects-that-touch-the-border-of-an-image) but the solution provided just works if the image consists mainly of a background, which may not be necessarily my case. I tried using `scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes` but it does not work with regions that touch the boundary:

[image]

Is there some other way to make this work for *all* regions (including those that touch the boundary)?

EDIT: I don't mind which one is the filled region and which one is not. Namely, if the values are inverted, it is fine too. I just need a binary division, it doesn't matter which ones are filled and which ones are not, as long as the boundaries correctly separate the two kinds.

Comment: How do you define that a shape has to be filled ? For example in the bottopm right corner: why should the small blob not be filled, but the surrounding one yes ?

Comment: have a look at opencv floodFill function

Comment: @jeandemeusy I've updated the question with some relevant information, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: First of all you need to define all the contours by opencv CLEARLY. then fillPolly or fillConvexPolly will help you

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk What do you mean by "clearly"? Why do you say that the contours are not defined?

Comment: They are not yet detected by any function, you need to detect them first of all and get the points. Even they seem clear, it ll not be easy to get the contours

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk The boundaries have been detected by `cv2.Canny`. That is how I get the first binary image.

Comment: You'll get totally different results depending on where you start filling so, in that sense, it is unclear.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Even taking into account the last paragraph of the OP? I think there are only two possible results, and both of them are fine for me (one is just the complement of the other).

Comment: Do you have a decent PNG version of the starting image rather than the JPEG posted please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, I didn't know StackOverflow ruined the quality that much. I've updated the question with the original PNG.

Answer (score -1):

Since my last answer missed the point of the corner issues.
I tried to find a better fitting solution:
I also tried the morphological transformation like cv2.morphologyEx
but the results were not so good at all in the end.

So : why not adding an artificial border to close all contours ?
General workflow:
a) extend image and add border
b) apply some gaussian filter
c) convert to greyscale
d) find contours in tree hierachy structure
e) use the strucuture to find the right contours

So the code looks like:

```
import cv2
from random import randrange

# read the image
image = cv2.imread('QFqC8m.jpeg')

#we extend the image to add a small border
borderSize = 1
image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image,borderSize,borderSize,borderSize,borderSize,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255,255,255])

# convert the image to grayscale format
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Binary image', img_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#we apply GaussianBlur filter
image_blured = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(3,3),0)
cv2.imshow('Blured image', image_blured)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# apply binary thresholding
ret, img_thres = cv2.threshold(image_blured, 50, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# visualize the binary image
cv2.imshow('Threshold image', img_thres)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# detect the contours on the
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=img_thres, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # Remove redundant dimension of hiers.
# we iterate the hierachy
# openCV represents it as an array of four values :
# 0      1            2          3 
#[Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]
# Find contour with the maximum area our artifical box is the largest contour
# its the outside square box
rootSquareContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
rootSquareContourArea = cv2.contourArea(rootSquareContour)

# we do search the right first tree lvl via hand
#first lvl
root_idx = contours.index(rootSquareContour)
root_hierarchy = hierarchy[root_idx]
child_idx = root_hierarchy[2]  # Index of the first child

while child_idx != -1:    
    child_hierarchy = hierarchy[child_idx]
    #get the contour
    c = contours[child_idx]
    #we draw it with random color
    cv2.fillPoly(image,pts=[c],color=(randrange(255),randrange(255),randrange(255)))
    #get next element
    child_hierarchy = hierarchy[child_idx]
    child_idx = child_hierarchy[0]  #get next element on same lvl

    #TODO might need not all lvl ? 
    if child_idx==-1: #switch to next lvl
        child_idx = child_hierarchy[2] 
                

cv2.imshow("Filled Contours", image)
cv2.imwrite("filled.jpg", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: ouput]

There is still some work todo but the code explains the idea behind.
A good explanation about the hierachy structure could be found [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/opencv-findcontours-detailed-guide-692ee19eeb18)

Comment: This clearly has the same problem I explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: i must have missed the point, but since you do have the contours 
you could simply add the edge points to the contours in some way

see some similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19809030/14105642

Comment: I updated the example, now it addresses your problem